# Improve AC flow to secondary ducts

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, ductwork, central-air, heat-pump

I have an AC which has 3 ducts coming out of it.  Only one duct gets flow - I'm guessing the AC fan blows right into it.  What can I do to improve the flow?

Comment: This is the most annoying problem I face as a home owner.  I despise it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to restrict the flow through that duct, either by installing a damper like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xh7/R-100396929/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053) in the duct, or by installing an adjustable register at the duct outlet, and closing it off until you get similar flow out of all three ducts.

Comment: OK, finally dealing with this problem.  The issue is that the flexible ducting came TOTALLY loose from the register box - amazing!  That'll cause a flow issue.